# how to replace 2nd filed of line separated by comma with a value stored in variable

Tags: unix, awk, sed

i have a line as below and all fields separated by comma:

I want to replace 2nd filed which is 11:50:21.444 with a value stored in variable "b"

```
01-01-2022,11:50:21.444,1234543233443,0,0,0,0,1
```

I tried using sed
cat abc.csv| sed 's/$2/$b/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you find yourself talking about fields you should use awk rather than sed or grep since awk has a concept of fields while the others don't and awk can do literal string replacements while sed can't.

```
awk -v b="$b" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2=b; print}' abc.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not expanded in single quotes.

Also, sed has no idea of columns.

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/$1,'"$b"/ abc.csv
       ^  ~~~~~  ^  ~~~~~
       |     |   |    |
start of     | Comma  |
the string   |       No comma
          No comma   again
```

Note that it can break if `$b` contains any characters special to `sed`, e.g. `/`.